# Geolocation on JQuery Mobile application

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

In my form I have 3 hidden inputs that is intended to get user's current latitude and longitude and send both to MySQL database.
I have tried some code but when I run it in the mobile environment, it shows clearly that both inputs are not populated with latitude and longitude.

HTML code

```
<div id="clockinPage" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
    <div id="wrapper_top_image">
       <div id="top_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="authentic">The information below will be used as Clock-In register.</div>
    <div data-role="content" >
        <div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
            <form id="cname" align="left" action="post" data-ajax="false" >
               <label for "id">Employee's Name:</label><br/>
               <select name="id" id="id">
               <option value=""></option>
               </select><br/>
               <label for "job_id">Job's Name:</label><br/>
               <select name="job_id" id="job_id">
               <option value=""></option>
               </select><br/>
               <input type="hidden" name="latitued" id="latitued" value=""><br/>
               <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="" >
               <input type="hidden" name="goo_map_api" id="goo_map_api" value="">
               <input type="submit" value="Clock-In" id="enviar_in" data-inline="true">        
            </form>
      </div>
   </div
</div>
```

JQuery Script

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#clockinPage', function() {

    var Geo={};

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }

    //Get the latitude and the longitude;
    function success(position) {
        Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        populateHeader(Geo.lat, Geo.lng);
    }

    function error(){
        console.log("Geocoder failed");
    }

    function populateHeader(lat, lng){
        $('#latitued').html(lat);
        $('#longitude').html(lng);
        $('#goo_map_api').html("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=false");
    }
```

});

When I try to post the information from the above form, it return the following error: 
**Application Error - There was a network error. (file:///android_asset/www/post?id=1&job_id=2&latitued=&longitude=&goo_map_api=)**

This clearly shows that it gets the input select id, the input select job_id but the 3 left, latitude, longitude and goo_map_api are empty.
Does anyone knows what be happening?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if check, just have: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);